# OpenCL Array Indexing Seems Broken

Tags: opencl

I've got a kernel with a simple array declaration and initialization, and an extra function "get_smooth_vertex(...)", which I have changed so as to demonstrate a problem:

```
//More const __constant declarations
const __constant int edge_parents[12][2] = {    {0,1},  {0,2},  {1,3},  {2,3},  {0,4},  {1,5},  {2,6},  {3,7},  {4,5},  {4,6},  {5,7},  {6,7} };
//More Functions
float3 get_smooth_vertex(const int edge_index, const float* cube_potentials) {
    int i1 = edge_parents[edge_index][0];
    int i2 = edge_parents[edge_index][1];
    if (i1==i2) return (float3)(0);\n"
    return (float3)(1);\n"
}
__kernel void march(const __global float* potentials, __global float* vertices, __global float* normals, const __constant float4* points, const int numof_points) {
    //Lots of stuff.
    //Call get_smooth_vertex(...) a few times
    //More stuff.
}
```

The if path in "get_smooth_vertex(...)" always seems to get executed!  Now, I can't imagine why this would be, because each pair in "edge_parents" is different.  I checked "edge_index", and it is always >= 0 and always <= 11.  Furthermore, none of the variables are aliased in global or local scope.  The kernel (and host code, FWIW) compiles with no warnings or errors.

So, I can't figure out what's wrong--why would the indices equal each other?  Alignment, maybe?  Am I just completely forgetting how C works or something?  Watch—it's going to be royal user error . . .

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code and the comparison works just fine (after removing the trailing `\n"`) . You have probably made a mistake when evaluating the return value of `get_smooth_vertex()`. But this is hard to tell without code that shows how it is called.

Comment: In this case, I just outputted the result directly; so it was pretty hard to misinterpret.  In practice, because the table was so small, I rewrote it to use a switch statement, which fixed the problem and is probably faster anyway :P